# rails 3 conditions and calculations across date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, multiple-conditions

Querying from date_start to date_end, I need to verify that on each date the quantity available for a given product meets a threshold.

```
@inventories = Inventory.where(['product_id IN (?) AND date_available >= ? AND date_available <= ? AND quantity >= ?', @products, @date_start, @date_end, params[:quantity]]).all
```

This query generates inventories that meet the criterion on any given date.  However these conditions need to be met on EACH date for a given product. Thus,

```
@products = @inventories.map(&:product).uniq
```

***Q1*** How do I now extrapolate all available_products (i.e. that quantity >= ? on each date) and

***Q2*** I need to sum the price for each date of each available_product, in order to sort the view by price

***Edit ***

Given a suggested answer, I think it may be wise to provide example data to further clarify
`product_id`  `date_available`  `quantity`  `price_1`  `price_2`
 1  ---- 2014-05-27  ----  3  ----  35  ----  60
 1  ---- 2014-05-28  ----  3  ----  35  ----  60
 1  ---- 2014-05-29  ----  3  ----  25  ----  50

2  ---- 2014-05-27  ----  3  ----  35  ----  60
 2  ---- 2014-05-28  ----  1  ----  35  ----  60
 2  ---- 2014-05-29  ----  3  ----  35  ----  60

3  ---- 2014-05-27  ----  3  ----  30  ----  55
 3  ---- 2014-05-28  ----  3  ----  30  ----  55
 3  ---- 2014-05-29  ----  3  ----  30  ----  55

@price = concatenation of 'price_1' and params[:quantity]

If search params are 2014-05-27..2014-05-29, quantity = 2
I should generate
  product 3 with price = 165
  product 1 with price 170
product 2 fails because on one of the dates the threshold is not met.

context: rails 3.2.17, postgresql, ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the query,

```
@inventories = Inventory.where(['product_id IN (?) AND date_available >= ? AND date_available <= ? AND quantity >= ?', @products, @date_start, @date_end, params[:quantity]]).select("date_available as date, product as product, sum(quantity) as quantity, sum(price) as price")).group('date, product').order('price')
```

From the above query u can get for every day & product quantity and price.

Comment: I may have been incomplete in my question, so I've elaborated and example above.  But the quantity should not be summed, the threshold needs to be defined for each record. I'm also uncertain why you suggest to group by date...